# Exclusive attribute value sets for different elements

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is a XML schema defining documents with `params` root element containing `atomicParam` and `complexParam` elements. Elements of both types have a `name` attribute.

```xml
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://companyname.org/"
                xmlns:tns="http://companyname.org/"
>

        <element name="params" type="tns:ParamsType"/>

        <complexType name="ParamsType">
                <sequence>
                        <element name="atomicParam" type="tns:AtomicParamType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        <element name="complexParam" type="tns:ComplexParamType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="ComplexParamType">
                <simpleContent>
                        <extension base="string">
                                <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required"/>
                        </extension>
                </simpleContent>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="AtomicParamType">
                <simpleContent>
                        <extension base="string">
                                <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required"/>
                        </extension>
                </simpleContent>
        </complexType>

</schema>
```

My goal is to apply the following constraint to the `name` attribute:

1. If any `atomicParam` has some value (say `foo`) of the attribute none of `complexParam` elements should have the same value of this attribute. At the same time, another `atomicParam` could have `foo` in the `name` attribute.
2. If any `complexParam` has some value (say `bar`) of the attribute none of `atomicParam` elements should have the same value of this attribute. At the same time, another    `complexParam` could have `bar` in the `name` attribute.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using XSD 1.0: there is a way to enforce the uniqueness of values, but not across different elements in the way it is required here.

It should be possible in XSD 1.1 using assertions:

```
<xsd:assert test="not(atomicParam/@name=complexParam/@name)"/>
```